# UNIX - Replacing variables in sql with matching values from .profile file

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to write a shell which will take an SQL file as input. Example SQL file:

```
SELECT *
    FROM %%DB.TBL_%%TBLEXT
  WHERE CITY = '%%CITY'
```

Now the script should extract all variables, which in this case everything starting with %%. So the output file will be something as below:

```
%%DB
%%TBLEXT
%%CITY
```

Now I should be able to extract the matching values from the user's .profile file for these variables and create the SQL file with the proper values.

```
SELECT *
    FROM tempdb.TBL_abc
  WHERE CITY = 'Chicago'
```

As of now I am trying to generate the file1 which will contain all the variables. Below code sample -

```
sed "s/[(),']//g" "T:/work/shell/sqlfile1.sql" | awk '/%%/{print $NF}' | awk '/%%/{print $NF}' > sqltemp2.sql
```

takes me till

```
%%DB.TBL_%%TBLEXT
%%CITY
```

Can someone help me in getting to file1 listing the variables?

Comment: Could you post file1, so we can understand the data we are working with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` and `sort` to get a list of unique variables, as per the following transcript:

```
$ echo "SELECT *
        FROM %%DB.TBL_%%TBLEXT
        WHERE CITY = '%%CITY'" | grep -o '%%[A-Za-z0-9_]*' | sort -u
%%CITY
%%DB
%%TBLEXT
```

The `-o` flag to `grep` instructs it to only print the matching parts of lines rather than the entire line, and also outputs each matching part on a *distinct* line. Then `sort -u` just makes sure there are no duplicates.

---

In terms of the *full* process, here's a slight modification to a `bash` script I've used for similar purposes:

```
# Define all translations.

declare -A xlat
xlat['%%DB']='tempdb'
xlat['%%TBLEXT']='abc'
xlat['%%CITY']='Chicago'

# Check all variables in input file.

okay=1
for key in $(grep -o '%%[A-Za-z0-9_]*' input.sql | sort -u) ; do
    if [[ "${xlat[$key]}" == "" ]] ; then
        echo "Bad key ($key) in file:"
        grep -n "${key}" input.sql | sed 's/^/   /'
        okay=0
    fi
done
if [[ ${okay} -eq 0 ]] ; then
    exit 1
fi

# Process input file doing substitutions. Fairly
# primitive use of sed, must change to use sed -i
# at some point.
# Note we sort keys based on descending length so we
# correctly handle extensions like "NAME" and "NAMESPACE",
# doing the longer ones first makes it work properly.

cp input.sql output.sql
for key in $( (
    for key in ${!xlat[@]} ; do
        echo ${key}
    done
) | awk '{print length($0)":"$0}' | sort -rnu | cut -d':' -f2) ; do
    sed "s/${key}/${xlat[$key]}/g" output.sql >output2.sql
    mv output2.sql output.sql
done

cat output.sql
```

It first checks that the input file doesn't contain any keys not found in the translation array. Then it applies `sed` substitutions to the input file, one per translation, to ensure all keys are substituted with their respective values.

This should be a good start, though there may be some edge cases such as if your keys or values contain characters `sed` would consider important (like `/` for example). If that *is* the case, you'll probably need to escape them such as changing:

```
xlat['%%UNDEFINED']='0/0'
```

into:

```
xlat['%%UNDEFINED']='0\/0'
```